# D3.JS theta in force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

**Can anyone please elaborate the significance of theta and the cases or situations where it can be used?**

Actually I am trying to make visual representation of graph but it is not giving ideal position of nodes. Because it contains too many cycles which is making the graph unclear. 
Currently I am using force layout in d3js. Please give the effects of the usage of theta in this case.

**Also if you have any other idea please be generous to inform.**

Comment: Did you have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-theta)? Theta alone doesn't really affect the layout of the graph.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck adjusting the charge and link strength parameters.

Comment: But what factors are needed to consider while changing charge and linkStrength? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [jsfiddle with sliders](http://jsfiddle.net/tristanreid/kLu3hm1g/) based on MaxF's excellent answer and MBostock's canonical [force layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

Note that if you want to load d3 block examples into a fiddle, you can replace `d3.json(function(error, json)` with:

```
function load(json) {
    // same code as d3.json(...
}

load({
  "nodes":[
   {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
   {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
   //... copy this from the block
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to learn and experiment with how the forces affect the graph was to make temporary sliders that you can play with to watch how changing forces affect things in real time.

For example, in the html I put this (a table was just the quickest and dirtiest way to format it):

```
<form oninput="chargeOut.value=chargeInput.value">
<table style="width:150px">
  <tr><td colspan="2">Charge: 
     <output name="chargeOut" for="chargeInput"> </output>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
     <input type="range" id="chargeInput" name="chargeInput" min="-350" 
       max="-1" value="-60" style="width:100%">
  </td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<form oninput="linkStrOut.value=linkStrInput.value">
<table style="width:150px">
  <tr><td colspan="2">Link Strength: 
     <output name="linkStrOut" for="linkStrInput"> </output>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
     <input type="range" id="linkStrInput" name="linkStrInput" min="0" 
        max="1" value="0.03" step="0.01" style="width:100%">
  </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and in the script I put this:

```
d3.select("#chargeInput").on("input", function () {
    force.charge(chargeInput.value).start()
})

d3.select("#linkStrInput").on("input", function () {
    force.linkStrength(linkStrInput.value).start()
})
```

You can then do the same for chargeDistance, friction, etc. Once you've done that you can figure out what settings you prefer and make those your default.

Regarding theta, as they said above won't change how it looks but [as per the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#theta), it can help speed up large graphs. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for it